# Will adding a libreoffice ppa automatically update the libreoffice that I just installed from the libreoffice official website?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, libreoffice, ppa

I  manually downloaded the latest deb files for LibreOffice 5.4.2 from [LibreOffice's official website](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/) and installed LibreOffice 5.4.2 from the deb files.

But I realized I won't get automatic updates for LibreOffice, so I would like to add [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to my repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

I haven't run the above command, and have a question. Will adding a new PPA for LibreOffice update the LibreOffice that I just installed from the LibreOffice official website? Or shall I uninstall the LibreOffice that I just installed and install from the PPA, in order to get auto update from the PPA?

Comment: It is better to remove and install from a PPA. It may be updated from the PPA, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer as the correct one. It may help others.

Comment: Currently Official is overriding LibreOffice's PPA on 14.04, see, https://askubuntu.com/questions/966179/how-to-get-a-repository-to-override-all-other-repositories-for-all-software-in?noredirect=1#comment1546877_966179 .  And, yes, remove all the manually installed, then add the PPA like user68186 says.

Answer (score 7):

#### It is best to remove the LibreOffice from original website

I don't know if the remnants of the other version will create any problems. Removing it is safer. The wiki linked below seems to say the same thing.

You can do it using `Ubuntu Software Center` or from the terminal. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt remove libreoffice
```

This will uninstall the LibreOffice but keep your settings.

#### Add the PPA

Enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

#### Update the lists

Enter:

```
sudo apt update
```

This will make sure the updated version from the PPA will be installed.

#### Finally install LibreOffice again

Enter:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice

Comment: *Why* do you recommend to remove the LibreOffice from the website?

Comment: I don't know if the remnants of the other version will create any problems. Removing it is safer. The wiki linked above seems to say the same thing.

Comment: @dessert: user68186's advice is a reasonable precaution, as trying to install the same program from different packages may cause issues if they both try to provide and use some of the same files. However, LibreOffice packages their debs and associated files with specific version numbers precisely so they don't conflict. For example, the downloaded executable is libreoffice5.4 and the Ubuntu package is just libreoffice; they work fine side by side so you don't need to uninstall first.

Comment: Packaging between the two repositories may differ.  You should remove old one because new packages may have different names and prerequisites.  Installing new one might leave copies of some old files floating about. I'd suggest you are careful to remove not only the original packages, but also purge the configuration files.